# Simple continuous integration from cron?

Tags: jenkins, cron, continuous-integration, build-automation, buildbot

Does anybody know about (or have experience with) a simple continuous integration system that can be run via cron and produce a static HTML report?

Tools like Jenkins and BuildBot all seem to need their own daemon processes.  (Which in my case means I need to get time from sysadmins to set up. Not gonna happen.)

Ideally, I'd like an output report that looks like:
http://buildbot.buildbot.net/#/console

That is, one row per revision and one column per build config. With a green/red status on each.

Comment: Jenkins is not hard to install.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the reason why people don't run CI systems in cron is that they rapidly outgrow cron.